# What is the maximum skill that these 2 magic cards can play?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I'm trying to write a program with C/C++ that solve the problem below, I was wondering can we use treap to deal with it?

> ### Description
>
> There are 2n magic cards, and each magic card has two positive integers a and b. Divide these magic cards into 2 heaps, each with n cards. The skill value that a bunch of magic cards can play is the product of the smallest a and the smallest b in the heap. You have a super power that can swap the a and b values on a magic card and use this ability indefinitely. You want to know how to divide the magic cards into 2 heaps (you can use super powers). What is the maximum skill that these 2 magic cards can play?
>
> ### Input
>
> The first behavior is a positive integer n, indicating that there are 2n magic cards;
>
> The next 2n lines, each line of two positive integers ai, bi, represent two values on each magic card;
>
> For 60% of the data, 1<=n<=10^3;
>
> For 100% of the data, 1<=n<=10^5, 1<=ai, bi<=10^9.
>
> ### Output
>
> Output a positive integer indicating the maximum skill value.
>
> ### Sample input
>
> ```
> 2
> 1 2
> 3 4
> 5 6
> 7 8
> ```
>
> ### Sample output
>
> ```
> 32
> ```

Sample output means 1*2+5*6=32

---

This test data is made by myself:

input:

```
3
8 1
2 7
5 4
2 6
4 6
5 3
```

output:

```
17
```

Output means 1*5+2*6=17

I am going to use the struct to do this, let's see what result OJ will give tomorrow (probably TLE).

Comment: Are you writing in C or C++? The answers should be completely different! Also, what have you tried and where are you having problems?

Comment: hey  Jonathan, I haven't written the code yet. The problem is from my algorithm class, so the answer should be fixed.

Comment: Hi @Lizzie  welcome on Stack Overflow! It is necessary to show an attempt at solving the problem before asking for help. People will happily help you once this requirement is fulfilled. It is done by showing some minimal code and describe what you were trying to achieve by doing so. Wishing you the best here :)

Comment: hey @axelduch, sorry, I apologize. I'm just at the very beginning of solving the problem, I haven't figure out which data structure and algorithm should I use

Comment: I had not even heard of a “treap” until reading your question.  A Google search “define:treap” gives a variety of leads — Wikipedia and Wiktionary among them.  My immediate reaction to the headline descriptions of treaps is “No; they won’t help you”, but it is no more than a gut reaction formed without having any good understanding of what treaps are useful for.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Treap is a data structure which combines binary tree and binary heap (hence the name: tree + heap ⇒ Treap).you can have more information from this page:https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/treap.html

Comment: According to [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/treap): _A treap [is a] type of randomized binary search tree where nodes are labelled with randomly chosen priority values and which is simultaneously a heap on those priorities._  Yes, it's a tree; but it's a randomized tree and I'm not clear how a randomized tree would help you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah..this is what I'm trying to figure out. Considering the time limit is 1000 ms, I think it may be because the time complexity of the heap is O(logn), so it's time-saving.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some idea from the problem hint, first use super power to turn all cards into `a<b`, sorting by a value from small to large.

The smallest a is fixed in the first heap, and enumerated from the second smallest value of a. Assuming enumeration to a[i], put all cards after i (including i) in the second heap, and put all the cards before i into the first heap.

At this time, we need to select n-i+1 from the second heap to put into the first heap. The strategy chosen is as follows:

- Sort all the cards of the second heap from small to large based on b value, then select the first n-i+1 or the next n-i+1 for the first heap.

In fact, it is to find the card with the first smallest b value or the n-i+1 big b value. This process is maintained with treap, and the total time complexity is O(nlogn).